# How do I skip extracting a value that is None in Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently working with Python requests to get data from an API. I'm trying to have a nested request within the request depending on the value received from one of the responses. So basically, I make a request and one of the fields returned is `uid`. I want again to pop that value into another request and that value makes part of the url. eg. `f"https://registry.nbnatlas.org/ws/dataResource/{uid}"`.
The only issue is that some responses have a null value for the `uid` field and this throws an error when making the nested request.

What I am trying to do is to skip the second request if the `uid` field is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `if uid is not None:` before the second request